# Green screen on HDMI monitor from MacBookPro

Tags: mac, display, macbook-pro, hdmi, displayport

I connected my MacBookPro into an HDMI monitor ([Dell U2312HM](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&sku=320-2807)) using a DisplayPort-HDMI cable. The result is a green screen as you can see in this video that I've uploaded just now:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3I7SCNXLlo

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Are you touching the cable to cause the interference patterns? Can you provide a link to the product page for the Displayport-HDMI cable you are using?  Is this cable brand new, or does it show any damage at all?  Are either the Displayport on the Macbook Pro or the HDMI port on the monitor damaged?

Comment: No, I'm not touching the cable! The cable brand is not well known, anyway it's Pluscom. The cable is brand new. I don't think the ports are damaged. One more point: I connected the Mac to another hdmi tv with the same cable and it works. In the first post I didn't say this: on the Dell monitor I'm using an hdmi-dvi adapter because the monitor have no hdmi port. Adapter brand is Nilox.

Comment: is the adapter HDMI to DVI-D?  Is it a unidirectional adapter?  Your monitor has a Displayport... your Mac has a Displayport.  But instead, you use a Displayport to HDMI adapter, an HDMI cable, and a HDMI to DVI adapter.  That's where your problem is.  When you remove the last adapter, everything works fine.  Solution?  Get a Displayport cable and use that.

Comment: Yes, adapter is HDMI to DVI-D, but don't know what you mean with unidirectional. Wait, I don't use a Displayport to HDMI adapter, but only the HDMI to DVI adapter to connect in the monitor. I don't get why it hasn't work! I buy the cable DisplayPort-HDMI because I want to connect the Mac also to other Tv's.

Comment: Too many adapters can cause issues.  You can see this when you remove the last adapter and it works.  Unidirectional... works in both directions.  Maybe the adapter you purchased is ONLY for converting DVI-D to HDMI (as in out from a DVI-D connection on a video card) and not the other way.  I don't get why people don't understand the importance of specific and exact details.

Comment: Too many? But I'm using only ONE adapter. If I remove the adapter I will not able to connect the cable hdmi plug to the monitor! The adapter box says "This adapter consent to connect every peripheral video",nothing about unidirectional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution buying [this cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002XVYZ82), it works.

Comment: Which cable?  link is dead

Comment: Link points to "StarTech.com 6ft (2m) Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort 1.2 Cable - 4K x 2K UHD Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort Adapter Cable - Mini DP to DP Cable for Monitor - mDP to DP Converter Cord (MDP2DPMM6)"